# django-relationships:RelationshipStatus matching query does not exist

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to use "coleifer/django-relationships" to create user relationship system in my site. But got problem in the very beginning step:
I followed the documentation, installed it successfully. Then added "relationships" into INSTALLED_APPS.
The documentation told me the next step is to run

```
django-admin.py syncdb
```

I did that, but got many errors, like:

```
ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
```

So I ran "python manage.py syncdb" instead. It seems OK.
Then I tried to use user model in command line, just follow the documentation (added two users before did that):

```
>>> john = User.objects.get(username='john')
>>> rel = john.relationships.add(jane)
```

Here comes the problem.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/relationships/models.py", line 96, in add
  status = RelationshipStatus.objects.following()
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/relationships/models.py", line 13, in following
  return self.get(from_slug='following')
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 132, in get
  return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 349, in get
  % self.model._meta.object_name)
DoesNotExist: RelationshipStatus matching query does not exist.
```

I found that RelationshipStatus table is empty.
Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: It seems that I have to create a "following" RelationshipStatus manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer: https://github.com/coleifer/django-relationships/issues/19
It's better to put the source code into your project directly rather than install it, so that when you run syncdb command, the table will be initialized.